# DOJO - Posting multidimensional json object to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, multidimensional-array, dojo

Sending multidimensional json object to the server (PHP) but it is not possible to send a multidimensional json object here is my code:

DOJO code:

```
var ObjArry=[];

var test1 = {key:value,  key:value,  key:value, key:value};
var test2 = {key:value,  key:value,  key:value, key:value};

ObjArry.push(dojoJson.toJson(test1 ,true));
ObjArry.push(dojoJson.toJson(test2 ,true));

request.post("services/service.php?where=saveObj",{ 
    data: ObjArry,
    handleAs: "json",
    sync: true,
    timeout:13000,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" }
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //output - null
});
```

Server side (PHP) code:

```php
//saveObj is php function
function saveObj(){
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

And the output I get is:

```
Array()
```

Comment: How are you logging your server-side output?

Comment: I have just added following function in php:

public function saveObj($item) {

           print_r($item);

}

Comment: Adding code in the comments is not a good idea, please edit your question. Also, this is not the entire code, how is `saveObj()` called and what is `$item` (what does it contain)? There's no problem with the Dojo code, so we should be looking at the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for replay, In PHP I have just print posted data from dojo but there is empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking closer to your Dojo code, I noticed a few things, the functions `dojo::toJson` and `dojo::fromJson` are deprecated in favour of `dojo/json::stringify` and `dojo/json::parse`, similar to how the `JSON` object works.

Just like [@Mike Brant said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24379178/1915448), you will have to use it on the entire array, for example:

```
ObjArray = dojoJson.stringify([ test1, test2 ]);
```

Then the request works properly, however, it indeed sends an empty request body. After removing the following header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

it started to work though, so I suggest removing it from your request, then it should work as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DgTLC/ (it sends a 404, but there is a request payload).

---

About your PHP I'm not sure either if you can use `$_POST` to retrieve the post body, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/1915448) you could use:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON-encode ObjArry after you have added elements to the array.

```
ObjArry.push(test1);
ObjArry.push(test2);

json = dojoJson.toJson(ObjArry);
```

Then pass json in Ajax call.